# NLTK is running out of RAM

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am a beginner in NLP and Python. I used multiple classifiers. The classifiers used are

```
NaiveBayes_classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainingFeats)
MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB()).train(trainingFeats)
BernoulliNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB()).train(trainingFeats)
LogisticRegression_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression()).train(trainingFeats)
SGDClassifier_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SGDClassifier()).train(trainingFeats)
LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC()).train(trainingFeats)
```

all these are from the standard NLTK and sklearn packages. Now when I am training all the classifiers I am running out of RAM. My server currently supports a 2gb ram which is not sufficient for these. The program is being killed due to insufficent ram. Is there a way to decrease the amount of memory consumed? or is there a way so that I can store the trained classifier on the disk and run it without loading it completely on to the ram?

Comment: I dont know if I am clear if you want more information I shall provide

Comment: You can use pickle to dump your classifier.

Comment: I tried doing a pickle dump but when I had to classify some test data then I should again load the pickled classifier which again leads to the same problem no ram

Comment: What is the pickle dump size? Can you try to load one pickle classifier at a time and predict? or its causing problem for even single classifier?